# Frescolib crashes in vanila nativescript when use multiples images

Tags: android, nativescript, fresco

In my app I have fresco LIB but when images from camera are too bigs and load more than 3 images the app crashes/exits with no error, just closes the app

any idea??

nativescript │ 2.5.4
tns-core-modules │ 2.5.2
tns-android │ 2.5.0
nativescript-fresco │ ^1.0.16 │

UPDATE:

**I ended up, making a thumb image in order to prevent android crashes.**

Comment: Try updating to the latest NativeScript CLI and tns-core-modules where a lot of improvements were introduced when working with large images and also built-in image caching is provided(meaning you do not have to use fresco) - https://docs.nativescript.org/best-practices/images-optimisations

Comment: I just update to 3.4 
and I did this test just this view

    <Image src="http://lorempixel.com/1920/1920" decodeWidth="100" decodeHeight="100" loadMode="async" />
 about 8 times...
And the app after scroll to the 3 o 4 image quits =(